# ggalluvial ordering stratum

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to make some sankey diagrams with the [ggalluvial package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html). I rather like it but I'm having problems controlling the order of the lodes. I'm using the alluvia format described at the start of the vignette.

Basically my diagram is showing subsets of level 2 and level 3 of one time point and how they move to another time point. The problem is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to force the order of the stratum as the diagram is unreadable without the order being correct. Here's my code:

```
library("ggalluvial")
library("ggplot2")
subsank_math = structure(list(`Winter Projection` = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                                5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Level 5", "Level 4", "Level 3", 
                                                                                                "Level 2", "Level 1"), class = "factor"), subgroup = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Level 3 (+)", "Level 3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         "Level 3 (-)", "Level 2 (+)", "Level 2", "Level 2 (-)"), class = "factor"), 
                              n = c(119, 102, 16, 10, 12, 1, 272, 544, 182, 151, 134, 22, 
                                    40, 239, 204, 326, 663, 225, 0, 15, 12, 44, 215, 219)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                          -24L), .Names = c("Winter Projection", "subgroup", "n"), class = "data.frame")




ggplot(subsank_math,
           aes(weight = n,
               axis1 = subgroup, axis2 = `Winter Projection`)) +
geom_alluvium(aes(fill = subgroup),
                  width = 0, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
geom_stratum(width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
geom_text(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE, reverse = FALSE)
```

Kinda strange that it orders the first axis according to the levels of the factor but not the second.
[image: Wrong ordering sankey]

Comment: I had a similar problem, and realised it was caused by having one or more identical levels in different stratum (in your case 'level 2' and 'level 3' are in _subgroup_ and _Winter Projection_. Under the hood the stratum (axis1, axis2, etc), must be reshaped as a single long factor, which mixes up the ordering. Solution: make sure all levels are unique across all stratum, or first reshape into Iode format as described by @Z.Lin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just started playing with the ggalluvial package myself, so I won't claim to understand how things work, but reformating the data frame into lode format (described near the end of the package's vignette) worked for me:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.lode <- subsank_math %>%
  mutate(subject = seq(1, n())) %>%
  gather(x, level, -n, -subject) %>%
  mutate(level = factor(level,
                        levels = c("Level 1", "Level 2 (-)", "Level 2",
                                   "Level 2 (+)", "Level 3 (-)", "Level 3",
                                   "Level 3 (+)", "Level 4")))

> head(df.lode)
    n subject                 x   level
1 119       1 Winter Projection Level 4
2 102       2 Winter Projection Level 4
3  16       3 Winter Projection Level 4
4  10       4 Winter Projection Level 4
5  12       5 Winter Projection Level 4
6   1       6 Winter Projection Level 4

ggplot(df.lode,
       aes(x = x, 
           stratum = level, 
           alluvium = subject,
           weight = n,
           label = level)) +
  geom_flow(aes(fill = level)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum") +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = levels(df$a1))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Very cool. I tried using the lode format before but obviously was missing something. Thank you!

Comment: (+1) [v0.6.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/news.html) introduces a warning message and a `make.unique()`-based workaround, but this is still the right solution for the problem posed.